# visual basic twittervb issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, api, exception, twitter

This code is throwing `TwitterAPIException` on this line

```
profilepic.ImageLocation = twitter.AccountInformation.ProfileImageUrl
```

I have a feeling it may be because it isn't authenticating but I'm not sure. any idea why i might be getting this, also how can i in my code check if twitter has authenticated me before trying to actually read data?

I have removed the private keys for privacy

```
Imports TwitterVB2
Public Class Form1
Dim twitter As New TwitterAPI

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles verify_btn.Click
    twitter.AuthenticateWith("", "", "", "")
    profilepic.BackColor = Color.White
    profilepic.ImageLocation = twitter.AccountInformation.ProfileImageUrl
    tw_name.Text = "HI" + twitter.AccountInformation.Name

    For Each Tweet As TwitterStatus In twitter.HomeTimeline
        tweets.AppendText(vbNewLine + vbNewLine + Tweet.User.ScreenName + vbNewLine + Tweet.Text + vbNewLine + Tweet.CreatedAtLocalTime + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + "..............................")
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tw_name.Click

End Sub

Private Sub profilepic_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles profilepic.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of TwitterVB.  :)

Because I stopped updating the library in 2011, TwitterVB was never updated to work with version 1.1 of the Twitter API.  I've gotten many, many requests to address this specific issue, so I have made an updated version of the DLL available here:

https://github.com/DWRoelands/TwitterVB/releases/tag/3.1.1

Please note that I have done no testing and that this DLL should be considered "pre-release".  If you have questions or issues, I'll do my best to answer them.  You can reach me via my GitHub page:

https://github.com/DWRoelands